# Windows7 desktop does not appear after installing Ubuntu on Asus N550JV DB71 laptop

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7

I have Asus N550JV DB71 laptop. I want to use both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

First I turned off UEFI mode. I disabled Secure boot and Fast boot choices in BIOS settings. Then I partitioned my drive into three partitions on laptop using Windows 7
I converted all drives to MBR partitions using `sudo gdisk /dev/sda` (using Ubuntu live CD).

Then I re-installed Windows 7 on `sda1` and Ubuntu 14.04 on `sda3`

On boot I chose windows from grub menu. I heard the startup sound of windows but the desktop didn't appear. I turned off PC using the power switch. Then I turned on, and Windows booted. Shutdown as normal in Windows, then on again, with the same problem as before (no desktop appears). Ubuntu boots normally.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved:

1. I converted all partitions (sda1,sda2 and sda3) to GPT  using Gparted.
2. I installed Windows 8.1 on sda1 (not recovery disc) in UEFI mode.
3. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on sda2 in UEFI mode.